# Android sqlite store date types

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date

I need to store dates in my app database and i need to know if is possible to create a table with a date type column in `Android Sqlite` like this:

```
"CREATE TABLE example1 (ex_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ex_date DATE)"
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not.

But you can use [`Date.getTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29), to have the timestamp (long in JAVA, INTEGER in SQLite), to be able to store and retrieve the date.

To retrieve the date from database, you will do :

```
new Date(cursor.getLong(yourColumnIndex));
```

And to store it :

```
contentValues.put("yourDateColumn", date.getTime());
```

Comment: ... or format date as string, or get floating point Julian day, or ...

Comment: yep, but integer is the fastest and lower way to store dates.

Comment: And who told you "fastest" was a requirement? Any of those methods have their own advantages and drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
/* Creating Table */
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDER_DETAILS
+ "("
+ OD_LOCAL_TIME + " TEXT,"
+ OD_SERVER_TIME + " TEXT "
+ ")";

db.execSQL(query);
```

Comment: -1 `TIMESTAMP` is not any recognized type to SQLite! `TIMESTAMP` will get  `NUMERIC` affinity [SQLite3 data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)!

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer question. You created `TEXT` columns. OP wants date data type. And now what?

Comment: `Text` is not desirable in this context.